# Entity Framework How can I filter my results by a property of a navigation property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a legacy class database that is represented by the following model.

```
public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public CourseLevel Level { get; set; }
    public float FullPrice { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }

    public IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public IList<Attendee> Attendees { get; set; }
}

public class Attendee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public decimal Tuition { get; set; }

    public Student Student { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get a list of classes that either a part of the course title or description or a part of a student's name matches my search string. The first part is easy.

```
List<Course> courses = db.Courses.Where(w => w.Title.IndexOf(searchString) > -1 || w.Description.IndexOf(searchString) > -1).ToList();
```

How do I now filter against w.Attendees.Student.Name?

I tried:

```
List<Course> courses = db.Courses
    .Where(w => w.Title.IndexOf(searchString) > -1 || 
           w.Description.IndexOf(searchString) > -1 ||
           w.Attendees.Any(a => a.Student.Name.IndexOf(searchString) > -1)).ToList();
```

And it just returns an empty list.

I'm still kind of new to Linq, I'm coming from Grails. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. This code isn't going to compile, let alone return an empty list (`Where()` doesn't return a `List<T>`). You simplified the example too much. The principle you show should work.

Comment: Did you try running only w.Attendees.Any(a => a.Student.Name.IndexOf(searchString) and debugging it? Are you sure it isn't empty? Your construct is correct, you are checking wheter any item in Attendees has a Student whose name contains a string.

Comment: Should be : a.Student.Name.Contains(searchString)

Comment: @jdweng While Contains does make more sense since he doesn't need the index, the calls are equivalent if you compare the returned index against -1

Comment: @victor That almost worked. I needed to add a couple of ToUpper() calls to make the search case insensitive. That also happens to be the first thing I tried yesterday when I started this whole mess. I also was using Contains(searchString) when this all started. I'm about to test the whole search, not just the navigation property.

Comment: You can use [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring) as reference regarding searching for a string in a string

Comment: @victor if you enter an answer, I'll accept it. I ran into a null reference error, but I added checks for all of the search fields an it worked like a champ. Thanks to everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running only `w.Attendees.Any(a => a.Student.Name.IndexOf(searchString)` and debugging it because `Attendees` could be null or empty, and the same is true for the `Student` property.

Also, in the off chance that your database isn't case insensitive, you should consider changing your code to reflect that:

`w.Attendees.Any(a => a.Student.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(searchString.ToLowerInvariant())`

The case sensitiveness **could** be the source of your problems too.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
List<Course> courses = db.Courses
    .Where(w => w.Title.Contains(searchString)|| 
           w.Description.Contains(searchString)  ||
           w.Attendees.Any(a => a.Student.Name.Contains(searchString))).ToList();
```